# Prove that: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n}+4^{n}}{3^{n}+5^{n}}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n}+4^{n}}{3^{n}+5^{n}}$ converges.

My attempt:

$$\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{\frac{2^{n}+4^{n}}{3^{n}+5^{n}}} \leq \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{\frac{2*4^{n}}{5^{n}}}= \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{2} * \frac{4}{5} $$

$$\limsup \frac{2^{n}+4^{n}}{3^{n}+5^{n}} \leq \limsup \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{2} * \frac{4}{5} = \lim \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{2} * \frac{4}{5} = \frac{4}{5}$$

I can continue from here if I knew that for $N>0, n>N$ the sequence elements are bounded with an upper bound say $q<1$ then use Cauchy's root test for convergence of series.

Can I say that? Can I say that the limsup can be an upper bound for all $n>N$ elements of the sequence if I didn't prove the sequence converges (I know it must converge since the series converges).

So, I need to prove that the sequence itselt converges.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just compare to a geometric series, no need to go for complicated things:

$\begin{cases}2^n+4^n<4^n+4^n\\3^n+5^n>5^n\end{cases}\quad$ thus $0<\dfrac{2^n+4^n}{3^n+5^n}<2\times\left(\dfrac 45\right)^n$

And since this one is a convergent geometric series $2\times \sum c^n$ with $|c|<1$, the original series is convergent (i.e. positive terms means $S_n\nearrow$ and bounded by the limit of the other series, thus convergent).

Answer (score 0):

Obvious with *asymptotic equivalents*:

$2^n+4^n\sim_\infty 4^n$, $\;3^n+5^n\sim_\infty 5^n$, hence
$$\frac{2^{n}+4^{n}}{3^{n}+5^{n}}\sim_\infty \Bigl(\frac{4}{5}\Bigr)^{\mkern -4mu n},$$
which is the general term of a convergent series.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use : $$\frac{2^{n}+4^{n}}{3^{n}+5^{n}}=\frac{2^{n}}{3^{n}+5^{n}}+\frac{4^{n}}{3^{n}+5^{n}} \leq \frac{2^{n}}{3^{n}}+ \frac{4^{n}}{5^{n}}$$