# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n + 4^n}{3^n + 5^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Based on this question:
[Prove that: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n}+4^{n}}{3^{n}+5^{n}}$ converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656943/prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n4n3n5n-converges)

I was curious if this:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n + 4^n}{3^n + 5^n}$$

could actually be evaluated, as it seems so close to just being a geometric series or something with a few manipulations, unless it is very complicated.

Comment: For every value of k numerator is lesser than denominator and at infinite it tends to zero so it converges

Comment: It's approximately $3.805283237$, I would not hope for closed form.

Comment: @NamburuKarthik That's necessary for convergence, but not sufficient.

Comment: Just a tiny modification to an easy sum often makes its very hard / impossible to find a closed form and often require completely different methods so being close if often not enough. This sum is not something that is easily evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reduced it
to a sum over
the function
$p(m, v)=\sum_{d | m}(-1)^{m/d} v^{d}
$,
but that's as far
as I can go.

I've seen that function
*somewhere*,
but I don't recall where.

Here's my derivation.

We only need to consider
these functions:

If
$a > b > 1$,
let
$s(a, b)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{a^n+b^n}
$

$\begin{array}\\
s(a, b)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{a^n+b^n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{a^n(1+(b/a)^n)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{a^n(1+r^n)}
\qquad r = b/a, 0 < r < 1\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{a^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kr^{nk}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{a^n}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^kr^{nk}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{a^n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{a^n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^kr^{nk}\\
&=\dfrac{1/a}{1-1/a}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} r^m \sum_{d | m}(-1)^d a^{-m/d}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{a-1}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} r^m \sum_{d | m}(-1)^d a^{-m/d}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{a-1}+t(r, 1/a)\\
t(u, v)
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} u^m \sum_{d | m}(-1)^d v^{m/d}
\qquad 0 < u, v < 1\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} u^m \sum_{d | m}(-1)^{m/d} v^{d}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} u^m p(m, v)
\qquad p(m, v)=\sum_{d | m}(-1)^{m/d} v^{d}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Very cool, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you have seen it in the contex of mobius inversion? I'm not sure...

Comment: If the sum involves $d^v$ then it is multiplicative. This is not.